# Javascript MVC: Object vs Model

Tags: object, javascriptmvc

What is the difference between a model as in the M in MVC javascript, and a simple object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A model is a specific type of class or object that is designed to interact with the data sets of your particular site or software. It also usually includes methods designed to simplify the process of accessing the data.

Simply: A "MODEL" is a specific and focused type of object meant to deal with data.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as XMO said.

For Example:
You have a Model "Foo" in "Yourapp.Models".
So you could listen in any controller to the model's method "create" with:

```
"{Yourapp.Models.Foo} created": function () {} ...
```

You can not achieve this that easily with a normal object.